# UI5 ListMode.SingleSelectMaster ignores ListitemType.Inactive

Tags: list, sapui5

I try to create a List that has the mode SingleSelectMaster, so that the last selected item is highlighted.
In my list there are a few ListItem, that are "Inactive", if i click on these the list isn't fire the itemPress event. That's fine! But the list is highlighting these elements, also the list provides a hover effect on the inactive elements.

```
<List itemPress="toDetailPage" mode="SingleSelectMaster" >
    <items>
        <CustomListItem type="Active" >
            <HBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                <Label text="Type: Active"/>
            </HBox>
        </CustomListItem>
        <CustomListItem type="Active" >
            <HBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                <Label text="Type: Active"/>
            </HBox>
        </CustomListItem>
        <CustomListItem type="Inactive" >
            <HBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                <Label text="Type: Inactive"/>
            </HBox>
        </CustomListItem>
        <CustomListItem type="Inactive" >
            <HBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                <Label text="Type: Inactive"/>
            </HBox>
        </CustomListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The "type" property is not similar to the "disable" property. There is no way to achieve a "disabled" list element easily in SAPUI5. What you can do is to implement a custom control for the customListItem in the "inactive state". Please refer to this guide on how to do custom controls:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.4/docs/guide/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db.html